# Netsuite Creating menu option

Tags: netsuite

As I said before, I'm new to Netsuite...

I want to add a menu / sub-menu option to Transaction,
Sports
   Baseball 
   Football
   Basketball

Where can I do that  ?

Thanks
Mark

Answer (score 1):

If what you are asking is how to have a dropdown field on your transaction you will have to create a custom record or list with your desire options, then create a Transaction Body Field which will be type List/Record and sourcing from your previously created list/record.
More Info about sourcing here:
https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=2mYdf-AnmFk

In the other hand if what you are asking is how to create a Drop Down menu at the top of the transaction page where the buttons are, is not possible, the best you can do is use the Actions Menu.
You would customize your transaction form and you will have a custom Actions Tab where you can set things there.

Hope that help.